# Is there any workaround on this SQL Datatable?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c++-cli

I have this CSharp WinForms code  that works well

```
            SqlConnection loginCon = new SqlConnection
                ("Data Source=MORTDECAI;Initial Catalog=d_Authentication;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;");
            SqlCommand connectionCommand = new SqlCommand
                ("Select * From d_Info where Username=@username COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS and Password=@password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", loginCon);

            connectionCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textUsername.Text);
            connectionCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textPassword.Text);

            connectionCommand.Connection = loginCon;
            loginCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adaptData = new SqlDataAdapter(connectionCommand);
            DataSet databaseData = new DataSet();
            DataTable virtualTable = new DataTable();

            adaptData.Fill(databaseData, "Login");
            virtualTable = databaseData.Tables["Login"];

            loginCon.Close();
            int count = databaseData.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            if (count == 1)
            {
                if (virtualTable.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "Administrator"){
                //some codes}
```

Notice the last line: `if (virtualTable.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "Administrator")`

When the same code is applied on C++/CLI, the last line doesn't work as intended. Here is the code in C++/CLI

```
        adaptData->Fill(dtbaseData, "AdminTable");
        dtTable = dtbaseData->Tables["AdminTable"];
        Database->Close();

        sqlCount = dtbaseData->Tables[0]->Rows->Count;
        if (sqlCount == 1) {
            if (dtTable->Rows[0][1]->ToString() == "Administrator") {
                this->Hide();
                res_load->Show();
            }
```

I get the following error:

[image: errorcode E1767]

but there is no error whenever I removed `[1]` from the code like this
[image: No Errors was thrown]

Is there any good way in handling this error?

Regards,

Joey

Comment: Not a C++ programmer, but does `Rows[0]->ItemArray[1]` (or `Rows[0]->Item[1]`?) change anything? I ask because `DataRowCollection[0]` returns the first DataRow and then calling `[1]`  on that in C# will use the [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0) property which is the default indexer, but I genuinely don't know if C++ appreciates default indexers

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, `Item[1]` indicates the sql column of the data from the given  row, in which the first row is `[0]`

Comment: So it should solve the problem.. ?

Comment: I still need to call the index number where the data is stored though

Comment: Do the datatable get results?  I think you are not getting any data from the database which is why it is failing.  check your connection string to make sure it matches working code.  Are you using same machine in the working and non working example?

Comment: *I still need to call the index number where the data is stored though* - is that not what I just advocated you do? In c#: `Rows[0][1]` in C++ `Rows[0]->Item[1]` or `Rows[0]->ItemArray[1]`? Column 1 being "Administrator"...

Comment: @jdweng yes, everything matches, it is just that one line that I can't seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cb53f9c-d075-4685-a4eb-12d36313ec89/how-to-access-the-ref-class-declared-datatable-?forum=vcgeneral). According to that post:

> Seems a problem of IntelliSense, which does not stop the compilation and execution of the program.

While it does appear to stop compilation for you (maybe I'm wrong?) I believe the workaround may still apply.

The suggested workaround in your case, based on the link given, would be:

```cpp
DataRow ^ row = dtTable->Rows[0];
if (row[1]->ToString() == "Administrator")
{
    this->Hide();
    res_low->Show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround I found is by doing this

```
                DataRow^ recAdmin = dtbaseData->Tables[0]->Rows[0];
                if (recAdmin->IsNull("AdminId")) {
                    throw gcnew IndexOutOfRangeException("No such Admin Exist!");
                } else{
                    MessageBox::Show("Login succsessfull");
                    res_load->Show();
                    this->Hide();
                }
```

[As shown by the solution posted here](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/adonet/parameterized.htm)